# Compiling "Thinking Forth" LaTeX source

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have a good book "Thinking Forth" which has LaTeX code availale. (http://thinking-forth.sourceforge.net)

The source code uses PSTricks, so I'm trying to remove the PSTricks dependent code. The biggest hurdle is to convert `\tip` environment which can be used as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{book}

    \def\tfoptions{6.14x9.21,2004,tip,tipno,leo,isbn,bnw}

    \usepackage{pst-all}
    \usepackage{pst-blur}
    \usepackage{pst-grad}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[\tfoptions]{tf}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=\linkcolor,citecolor=\linkcolor,urlcolor=\linkcolor]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    Hello.
    \begin{tip}
    Hello,     Hello.     Hello.    Hello.    Hello.    Hello.
    \end{tip}
\end{document}
```

to get this pdf results. The tip environment is smart that it shows the correct left or right finger pointing depending on the even/odd page.

[image]

I need to use three commands to make PSTrick code into pdf file.

```
latex --output=ps tip.tex
dvips tip.dvi
ps2pdf tip.ps
```

In the `tf.sty` file, tip environment calls the `\tipbox`.

```
\newenvironment{tip}{
\list{}{\listparindent 0pt\itemindent 0pt}
\item\relax
\stepcounter{tipc}%
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
{\iftip{\sc Tip}\small\else TIP\iftipno{} \tipno\fi\fi}\par\medskip\small
}{\par
\end{minipage}\egroup%
\leavevmode\label{tip-\thechapter.\arabic{tipc}}%
\tipbox
\endlist
}
```

The `tipbox` is defined as follows.

```
\def\tipbox{\@tempdima\ht\@tempboxa\@tempdimb\dp\@tempboxa
\advance\@tempdimb\ht\@tempboxa
\hbox to \linewidth{\leavevmode%
\ifodd\hypergetpageref{tip-\thechapter.\arabic{tipc}}%
\else\hss\hbox{\hss
\vbox to \@tempdima{\hbox{\includegraphics{pointing-r}}\iftipno\hbox{\small\tipno}\fi\vss}~}\fi
%%% <---
\pst@divide{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}{\pst@tempa}%
\psshadowbox[fillcolor=lightgreen,
cornersize=absolute,linearc=1.5ex,framesep=1.5ex,boxsep=false,
linecolor=midgreen,linewidth=0.3pt,
shadowcolor=lightgrey,shadowsize=3pt,blur=true]{\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
%%% ---> 
\ifodd\hypergetpageref{tip-\thechapter.\arabic{tipc}}%
~\vbox to \@tempdima{%
\hbox{\includegraphics{pointing-l}}\iftipno\hbox to 27pt{\hss\small\tipno}\fi\vss}\hss%
\else
\hbox to 2.5em{\hss}%
\fi
}
}
```

The `\tipbox` uses color definition from PSTricks.

```
\newrgbcolor{midgreen}{.9 .95 .9}%{.25 .62 .25}
\newrgbcolor{lightgreen}{.9 .95 .9}
\newgray{lightgrey}{.7}
```

I think I can 1) replace the  `\pst@divide{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}{\pst@tempa}%
    \psshadowbox` code into equivalent box function in TikZ and 2) remove the `\newrgbcolor` can remove the PSTriks dependency.

Is this correct? If so, how to replace the PSTricks code into TikZ?
If not, is there any easy code to replace the tip environment in gray box and pictures?

Style file and LaTeX source can be downloaded to be compiled from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10773282/share/2016/06/tip.zip

### EDIT

I could use `xelatex` to compile the source. This is the process.

Run `make tfoptions.tex` to get the option file.

Remove the `\newif\..` ... \fi, and also remove the pdftex setting in book class. Also remove fontenc and inputenc package.

```
%\documentclass[10pt,\tflang,pdftex]{book}
\documentclass[10pt,\tflang]{book}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

Run `make index` and `xelatex thinking-forth.tex` twice.

### EDIT2

For getting the cover.pdf.

Remove the line 8 - 14 (`\newif ... \fi`), remove the `\ifpdf` to have `%\else
\documentclass[10pt,\tflang,dvips]{book}` only.

Create `pagecount.tex` file and `\def\pagecount{306}`.

Create `isbn.eps`; go to http://smallpressbarcode.com and give ISBN number `978-0976458708`. Then generate the eps file to download and rename it into `isbn.eps`.

Run `latex --output=ps cover.tex; dvips cover.dvi; ps2pdf cover.ps`.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it? I think `xelatex` accepts `pstricks` and generates `pdf` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a first test with `tcolorbox`. If you can consider it, it could be further customized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{bbding}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{mytip}%
{enhanced, width=.8\linewidth,  before upper={Tip\par}, notitle, 
 overlay={\node[align=center, text width=2cm, anchor=north west, drop fuzzy shadow] 
          at (frame.north east) {{\Huge\HandLeft}\\ \thetcbcounter};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytip}
tip tip tip tip tip tip
\end{mytip}


\begin{mytip}
tip tip tip tip tip tip tip tip tip tip tip tip
\end{mytip}

\end{document}
```

[image]